# Creating list and using image in XSL -> XHTML

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I have two dictionaries, that will be combined in one output by using XSLT.

But the words wont come out as a list, but all in a line, and the two "lists" wont come side by side like this:

Swedish   English
word1     word2
word2     word3
word..    word..

Furthermore, my logo, which i have created a xpath for, won't show up.

Is my CSS file wrong, is my link.xml wrong or are my expectations of the output wrong?

english dictionary (english.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--<!DOCTYPE thesaurus SYSTEM "dictionary.dtd"> --> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="dictionary.xsl"?> 
 <!--Rootelementet kan enbart finnas 1 gang -->
  <dictionary> 
    <language>Engelsk</language>
    <author>
      <firstname>A</firstname>
      <lastname>B</lastname>
    </author>
    <word type="1">House</word> 
    <word type="2">Car</word>
    <word type="3">Fisch</word>
    <word type="4">Cat</word>
    <word type="5">Dog</word>
    <word type="6">Street</word>
    <word type="7">Water</word>
    <word type="8">Stone</word>
    <word type="9">Train</word>
    <word type="10">Color</word>
  </dictionary>
```

swedish dictionary (swedish.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--<!DOCTYPE thesaurus SYSTEM "dictionary.dtd"> --> <!--bortkommenterad så att man ska kunna validera jämte emot xsd schema-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="dictionary.xsl"?> <!-- Hamtar xsl styleesheet-->
  <dictionary> 
    <language>Svensk</language>
    <author>
      <firstname>A</firstname>
      <lastname>B</lastname>
    </author>
    <word type="1">Hus</word> 
    <word type="2">Bil</word>
    <word type="3">Fisk</word>
    <word type="4">Katt</word>
    <word type="5">Hund</word>
    <word type="6">Gata</word>
    <word type="7">Vatten</word>
    <word type="8">Sten</word>
    <word type="9">Tåg</word>
    <word type="10">Färg</word>
  </dictionary>
```

XML to link the dictionaries (links.xml)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="dictionary.xslt"?>
    <links>
        <dict>english.xml</dict>
        <dict>svenska.xml</dict>
        <svgLogo name="logo">boksvg.svg</svgLogo>
    </links>

The XSL file (dictionary.xslt)


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict">

<xsl:output
   method="xml"
   indent="yes"
   encoding="UTF-8"
/>



<xsl:variable name="dict1">
    <xsl:value-of select="/links/dict[1]" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="dict2">
    <xsl:value-of select="/links/dict[2]" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="logo" select="document(/links/svgLogo[@type='logo'])" />

<xsl:template match="/links">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
      <body>
      <div id="content">

        <div id="logoo"> <img width="100" height="100" src="{//svgLog/node()}"/> </div>

      <div id ="title"> <xsl:apply-templates select="document($dict1)/dictionary/language"/> ordlista</div>

        <div id="author">
          Författare:  <xsl:apply-templates select="document($dict1)//author"/> </div>


      <p class="words"><xsl:apply-templates select="document($dict1)//word">
                       <xsl:apply-templates select="document($dict2)//word">
              <xsl:sort order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates></p>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="word">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <br/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

CSS (style.css)

```
body
{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
}
/* Författaren är med small caps, storlek 16, centrerad och ett radbryte på 2,5 till nästa rad (orden).*/
#author{
text-align: center;
font-variant: small-caps;
font-size: 16pt;
padding-bottom: 2.5cm;
display: block;
}

/* Ordlistans språk står centrerad med small caps och storlek 24. Ett radbryte på 1,5 läggs till nästa rasd (författare)*/
#title{
text-align: center;
font-variant: small-caps;
font-size: 24pt;
padding-bottom: 1.5cm;
display: block;
}

/* Orden ska vara till vänster med storlek 12 och visas som en punktlista. */
.words{
font-family: "Georgia", serif;
font-size: 12pt;
text-align: left;
display: list-item;
 list-style: square;
 padding-left:20px;
 margin-left:20px;
}
```

Where do I do the change, in CSS, XSL, dictionaries or in the links xml?

Comment: That XSLT sample is not even well-formed XML as it has two nested `<xsl:apply-templates select="document($dict1)//word"><xsl:apply-templates select="document($dict2)//word">` and only closes one of them. And XSLT doesn't allow you nesting `xsl:apply-templates` so it is not clear what you want to achieve with your XSLT.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am trying to write out the words in rows. The ten english words in a column, and the swedish translation in the cokumn to the right of the english words.